# Unable to launch uiautomatorviewer in mac os high sierra

Tags: java, appium-android

Need help!

I have the problem, I can't run uiautomatorviewer on mac os high sierra

My path:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/XXX/Library/Android/sdk
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platforms-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/build-tools/27.0.1
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}
```

---

Get Error:

```
Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/mu/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/mu/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Thank you.

Hi, thank you for your help, 
When i used sdkmanager – -list, I Get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>
(SchemaModule.java:156) at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>
(SchemaModule.java:75) at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.
<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81) ................................... –
```

And then I try to start uiautomatorviewer and I  have this:

-

```
Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/mu/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/mu/Lib
rary/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I am wondering if the Java 11 causing this. What java version do you use?

Comment: Hi, you should use Java 8.

Comment: You just solved my problem! I got the same error as you got, but using java 8 instead of 11 fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the java path set correctly. To verify the java Environment Variables have been set correctly use this cmd: `java -version`

If the path is correct, still getting the same error then try to increase vm heap option. If you are using Terminal, run command

```
open -e /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
```

edit your studio.vmoptions file

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

and restarted Android Studio. Should work fine

If not also verify that Android Environment Variables have been set correctly. Use this command: `sdkmanager – -list`

By the way please find the below steps to set Android Studio:

**Step 1:** Download and Install latest version of Java 8 (JDK)

**Step 2:** Setup Java Environment Variables.

**Step 3:** Download and Install Android Studio.

**Step 4:** Install additional Android SDK tools(If not present).

**Step 5:** Setup Android Environment Variables :

ANDROID_HOME - (/YOUR_PATH_TO/android-sdk)
Ex : `export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk`

In Android SDK folder, there are three specific folders that you need to add to the Path variable

*platforms-tools*: folder (path – /YOUR_PATH_TO/android-sdk/platform-tools)

*tools* :folder (path – /YOUR_PATH_TO/android-sdk/tools)

*bin* : folder inside tools (path– /YOUR_PATH_TO/android-sdk/tools/bin)

Hope this helped.